# Insert 2-columns figure in Texstudio

Tags: floats

I have the same question about 2-pages figure. I use the code `figure*` then the figure appears very well; however, there is one word "figure" appears randomly in the text body, which I want to get rid of. Here is the code. I like it since it is very simple.

```
\begin{figure*}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale = 0.04] {Fig_BacktoBackConverter.png}
\caption{Back to Back converter and its control blocks}
\label{fig:ACsys3}
\end{figure*}
```

My packages are

```
\documentclass[journal,doublecolumn,10pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[normalsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage[normalsize]{caption}
\usepackage{wasysym}
```

Is anyone can help me? Many thanks !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Three quick comments: First, the document class option "doublecolumn" seems to be a bit non-standard; did you mean to write "twocolumn" (or just omit the option outright, since "twocolumn" is the default)? Second, the `subfigure` package has been deprecated for years; use `subig` or `subcaption` instead. Third, and most importantly, your code doesn't actually generate the problem you say is occurring. Please edit your code so that it actually generates the problem that needs to be fixed.